# Efficient way to carry out 2x2 window scan in matrix to count frequency of 2x2 patterns

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, conv-neural-network

Imagine I am given a n by n matrix of just 1s and 0s. My goal is to run a 2x2 scan and count the frequency of 1 bits in the 2x2 window and store the frequency in a resulting array. Take it that the given parameters are only the row length, col length and an array of [r,c] coordinates for the 1 bits in the matrix.

I am thinking of how I can optimize this. I had an idea to store the number of 1 bits per column in an array which will help in the counting as I shift the window. But is there a better way? Thanks!

Test case:

> [[ 1, 0, 0, 1], [ 0, 1, 0, 1], [ 1, 0, 0, 1]]

should result in [2, 4, 0, 0], where there are 2 sub matrices with 1 1bits in a window and 4 sub matrices with 2 1 bits in a window.

Comment: It was a coding challenge, and I experienced a time limit exceeded error while doing that brute force method of shifting the window and counting the number of bits, and updating the frequency result array one window at a time. Hence, I am trying to think of a  better solution

Answer (score 0):

As bit manipulation is much faster than array manipulation you can consider:

Make your array a one dimensional byte array.

```
    1,0,0,1 = 9  
    0,1,0,1 = 5  
    1,0,0,1 = 9  
    
    AND 1st row with 3 (2 bits) = 1  
    AND 2nd row with 3 (2 bits) = 1
    0101
    0011   AND
    ---- =
    0001

    shift 2 to left
    0001   -> 0100 = 4

    add them together = 5, 2 bits are set in your 2x2 scan
    
    loop this, top to bottom (2nd & 3rd row, etx) get all rows.
    
    Next shift all rows 1 to right and repeat actions above
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite follow for shift 2 to left = 4. Could you elaborate more to illustrate the example maybe? Also, I am given an array of the coordinates of the matrix where the 1 bits are at (might not even be sorted well). In that case, will this method be more efficient? Since I actually need to construct the matrix row by row.

Comment: I adjusted the answer, bit shifting is standard with most programming languages: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators